# What is the definition of expectation value in Nielsen and Chuang?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, nielsen-and-chuang

As someone who learned Quantum Mechanics prior to studying Quantum Computing, I am having problems with this book. For example, equation 2.92 is incorrect. That is the definition of expected value, not probability as stated in the text. Further down on the same page, they seem to confuse the term "Hermitian" with "idempotent". The book is in its 10th printing so I must be missing something. I would be grateful if someone could help me get on the right track.

Answer (score 5):

These are correct.

Equation 2.92: take this as the new definition of probability. In fact, you will already be familiar with this if you've studied quantum mechanics before. I assume you've probably seen something wit a wavefunction $\psi(x)$. You might then ask "What is the probability of finding the particle in the region $x>0$?", at which point, you'd calculate
$$
\int_0^{\infty}\psi^*(x)\psi(x)dx,
$$
which I might equally write as
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi^*(x)M(x)\psi(x)dx
$$
where $M(x)=1$ for $x\geq 0$ and 0 otherwise. This maps directly to the finite dimensional Hilbert space case where $\psi(x)$ is replaced by a factor $|\psi\rangle$, the integral (over the full range of positions) is replaced by an inner product, and $M$ is replaced by a matrix.

Confusing Hermitian and idempotent. I don't think so. N&C says:

> Observe that each measurement operator is Hermitian, **and** that $M_0^2=M_0$

(emphasis mine). You are observing two things: one is the Hermitian property, the other is idempotency.

Answer (score -3):

The expression $$
\int_0^{\infty}\psi^*(x)\psi(x)dx,
$$
is not part of Quantum Mechanics. The correct expression,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi^*(x)\psi(x)dx=1,
$$
is called the "Normalization Condition" and is part of the
definition of $\psi(x)$.
Also, your function $M(x)$ is usually written as $\theta(x)$ and is called the "step function".

That being said, I believe your second expression (in Quantum Mechanics) would be called "the expectation value of the step function". If you were to write that in what is called "Dirac Notation" it would be
$$
\langle\psi(x)|\theta(x)|\psi(x)\rangle.
$$

In light of these clarifications, N&C would have written this as
$$
\langle\psi(x)|\theta(x)^\dagger\theta(x)|\psi(x)\rangle
$$
and I don't think I have ever come across such a thing.

Comment: It’s ok to answer your own question, but it sounds as if you have another question to ask. You can ask another one for when you aren’t clear. I think people may be put off by the tone, which I think you are trying to be carful about, but it sounds like you doubt the validity of N&C.